# To check for the number of times a word occurs in a string. Both taken as input arguments . Python 3

Tags: string, python-3.6

```
def my_second_test(self):
    a = input("Enter your string")
    b = input("Enter word")
    d = a.split()
    counter = 0
    i = 0
    for i in d[i]:
        if b == d[i]:
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            print("word is repeated zero times")
    print("Word is repeated: ", counter, " times")
```

**What can I do to fix my code?**
**I am getting list indices must be integers or slices error**
Thanks

Comment: The problem is that here `if b == d[i]` Your `i` is no longer this one `i = 0`, but this one `for i in d[i]` (i.e. first string resulting from splitting `a`). And that is not a valid index of `d`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using `Regular Expressions`, here is an example to do that:-

```
import re
...
def my_second_test(self):
    a = input("Enter your string")
    b = input("Enter word")
    result = len(re.findall(b, a))
    if(result==0):
        print("word is repeated zero times")
    else:
        print("Word is repeated: "+result+ " times")
```